# JavaScript. Некорректно работает замена одного класса другим по клику

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть несколько блоков, содержащих однотипные календари и кнопку сбросить, по клику на дату она выбирается (то есть меняется класс у ячейки), но вот кнопка "сбросить" не сбрасывает выбранные даты. То есть не меняют измененный класс на исходный.
изначально колонка с датой имеет такой класс:

```
td.cal-av.cal-selectable
```

`.cal-av` указывает на то что дата **не выбрана**, после клика по ней класс у ячейки меняется на:

```
td.cal-nc.cal-selectable
```

эта замена прописана в коде модуля так и не нашел, где...
рядом с календариком есть кнопка 'сбросить' (`.acbf-reset-both.form-reset`), по клику на которую класс должен меняться обратно. Пробовал следующие варианты:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$(".acbf-reset-both.form-reset").click(function() {

         $(".cal-nc").addClass('cal-av');
         $(".cal-nc.cal-av").removeClass('cal-nc');     

});
});
```

и

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$(".acbf-reset-both.form-reset").click(function() {

         $(".cal-selectable").removeClass('cal-nc');
         $(".cal-selectable").addClass('cal-av');       

});
});
```

но в обоих случаях класс `cal-av` приписывается в конце то есть вместо того чтобы вернуться к исходному состоянию `td.cal-av.cal-selectable` получается так:

```
td.cal-selectable.cal-av
```

знаю что есть еще switchClass но что то он у меня никак работать не хочет...

до нажатия на кнопку сбросить (синим - выбранные даты, зеленым - свободные):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после нажатия на кнопку сбросить:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...как видно (подчеркнул красным) класс приписался не там где надо, а ниже (подчеркнул зеленым) как должно быть.

Comment: Я предположу, что вам это надо потому, что на этом завязаны стили, типа `.cal-selectable.cal-av`, но разве не лучше чуть изменить `css` ? В данном случае это не сложно

Comment: нет потому, что  где то в модуле написано что именно классы в такой последовательнсоти выбираются корректно, после сброса из за того что они написаны а бы как выбор происходит некорректно. Дело не в стилях а работоспособности скриптом что при нажатии на кнопку сброс все должно возвращаться в исходное состояние

Comment: ну вообще же без разницы как классы идут в атрибуте _class_

Comment: можете пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) или [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) сделать?

Comment: да я только сайт пример могу сбросить сбросить где это работает неправильно после первого сброса....

Comment: не, так не пойдет, можете выкинуть все не нужное и просто маленький пример сделать с этим календарем?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32578/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 1):

Порядок классов не имеет значения.

Но если очень надо, то

```
$(".cal-nc").attr('class', 'cal-nc cal-selectable')
```